# How to have a div to fixed position and other elements begin directly under this div

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is positionned fixed at the top of the page. It's the only one that is fixed.

How to have the rest of the content start directly (and precisely) under this fixed div. I cannot know the height of the fixed div (textual content mixed with images).

For the moment, I have positionned the content approximatively under it by inserting `<p>$nbsp;</p>` tag but it's not an elegant solution.

Comment: if height is not fixed then you need javascript, on page load get height & set it to fixed div

Answer (score 1):

Since  you don't know the height of the fixed element I suggest you get the height with javascript and set the margin-top of the element under it to the same height as the fixed element.

HTML

```
<body onload="onPageLoad()">
   <div id="fixed"></div>

   <div id="under-fixed">
       This is below the fixed element
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

Javascript

```
 function onPageLoad() { 

    //Get the height of the fixed element
    height = document.getElementById('fixed').offsetHeight;

    //Set the margintop of the element under the fixed one to the height of the
    //fixed one
    document.getElementById("under-fixed").style.marginTop = height+"px";
 }
```

EDIT:

If you don't want to do this with javascript, you can make the fixed element a position: sticky;

Then you have to make sure the sticky element is a direct child to the body (or a direct child to a container stretching all the way down to the bottom of your page). That position sticky element will then stay at the top of the page and the content below the sticky element will stay below it (untill you scroll ofcourse).

CSS

```
.sticky-element {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute position -

```
<div class="fixed-div">I  am a fixed div </div>
...
...
...
Rest of your elements...
```

apply the class as -

```
.fixed-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume `<div class="fixed-div">I  am a fixed div </div>` is direct child of `body`, if not, make the immediate parent of `.fixed-div`, to have `position: relative`

Comment: a position absolute won't stay at the same position on the screen as a fixed element when you scroll up/down.